# Can not connect due to proxy restricting HTTPS

Tags: support

I am connecting to Stackoverflow (and other Stackexchange) **behind a proxy at work**.

The proxy is blocking HTTPs connection but not all:

- https://openid.stackexchange.com/ works
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f fails

The second URLs is used by Stackoverflow when I click on the *Log in* link in the navigation bar.

I can not really do anything against it (I can still ask, but I highly doubt they will unblock the second url). And while I do understand the benefits of HTTPs over HTTP, I'd rather have the choice while connecting.

So, how can I connect alternatively ?

Can I export a cookie/local storage from another browser ?

Comment: What is this proxy you speak of? We are not in control of it - you will need to talk to those who operate it.

Comment: I updated a little my question and my expectation. And if there is no solution, so be it... I won't use SO at work.

Comment: see the [What else do I need](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100) section

Answer (score 3):

On the upshot, there's no need to sign in to browse/read anything on SO right now.

However, if I were you, I'd make the case at work for unblocking Stack Overflow. I don't know what your company is trying to gain by blocking HTTPS access to it.

Answer (score 1):

... that the most stupid proxy I've seen. It blocks connection on https://stackoverflow.com but not on https://meta.stackexchange.com ... Now I'm connected and happy.